# Running Javascript in python 3.2

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I am trying to create a python program that can log into a website. I have written the javascript that can log in; however, I haven't seen anything on running javascript in python. I am considering implementing the firefox javascript engine, seamonkey, but also don't know how to do that in python.

Any help would be wonderful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing *Python* with *JavaScript*, if at all possible, will be probably difficult and in my opinion not the ideal approach.

For a pure *Python* solution I suggest [mechanize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/0.2.5).

For a *JavaScript*-only solution, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) seems to be a very interesting framework.